# Unmarshalling nested list of xml items using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I've got such xml construction which I need to convert into java objects using JAXB:

```
<elements>
    <elemet>
        <type></type>
        <property1></property1>
        <property2></property2>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <name></name>
            </item>
            ...
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <name></name>
            </item>
        </items>
    </element>
</elements>
```

I should convert this construction not into element with nested list of items but into several elements one for every item. Here is example of Element class:

```
class Element {
    Integer type;
    String property1;
    String property2;
    Integer itemId;
    String itemName; 
}
```

I want to get list of them after unmarshalling. Type, property1 and property2 values should be the same for all list elements.
Is there any possibility to solve this problem using JAXB?

Comment: @alkis Can someone help me out with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58516572/jaxb-unmarshall-list-of-xml-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to define a custom [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html). The complicated part in your case is that you want to  map one XML `element` into multiple Java `Element` objects. This means that,  in Java., your `XmlAdapter` needs to be configured for collection of `Element` objects. Assuming your example XML fragment is part of a document:

```
<document>
   <elements> 
      <element>
          ....
      </element>
   <elements>
</document>
```

Then you will need to configure the `XmlAdapter` for the `List<Element>` field in the Java `Document` class:

```
class Document {
     @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CustomAdapter.class)
     List<Element> elements;
}
```

Then you your `CustomAdapter` class can receive a list of Element objects (corresponding to the actual XML structure with the nested items) and produce a list of Element with the structure you want.

For an example, check [JAXB XmlAdapter – Customized Marshaling and Unmarshaling](http://ashisharya2003.blogspot.com/2012/07/jaxb-xmladapter-customized-marshaling.html)

Answer (score 21):

**Main.java**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Element> elementList = new ArrayList<Element>();
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Element element1 = new Element();
        Element element2 = new Element();
        Item item1 = new Item();
        Item item2 = new Item();
        Elements elements = new Elements();

        item1.setId(1);
        item1.setName("Test1");
        item2.setId(2);
        item2.setName("Test2");
        itemList.add(item1);
        itemList.add(item2);

        element1.setProperty1("prop1");
        element1.setProperty2("prop2");
        element1.setType(2);
        element1.setItems(itemList);

        element2.setProperty1("prop11");
        element2.setProperty2("prop22");
        element2.setType(22);
        element2.setItems(itemList);

        elementList.add(element1);
        elementList.add(element2);

        elements.setElements(elementList);

        try {
            System.out.println("------- Object to XML -----------\n");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Elements.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(elements, System.out);

            System.out.println("\n------- XML to Object -----------\n");

            String xml = "<elements><element><items><item><id>1</id><name>Test1</name></item><item><id>2</id><name>Test2</name></item></items><property1>prop1</property1><property2>prop2</property2><type>2</type></element><element><items><item><id>1</id><name>Test1</name></item><item><id>2</id><name>Test2</name></item></items><property1>prop11</property1><property2>prop22</property2><type>22</type></element></elements>";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Elements elementsOut = (Elements) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
            System.out.println(elementsOut);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }
}
```

**Elements.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement(name="elements")
public class Elements {

    List<Element> elements;

    @XmlElement(name="element")
    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String res = "";
        try {
            for (Field field : fields) {
                res += field.getName() + " :\n" + field.get(this);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

**Element.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;

public class Element {

    Integer type;
    String property1;
    String property2;
    List<Item> items;

    public Integer getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Integer type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public void setProperty1(String property1) {
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }

    public void setProperty2(String property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="items")
    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String res = "\n";
        try {
            for (Field field : fields) {
                res += field.getName() + " : " + field.get(this) + "\n";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Item {
    Integer id;
    String name; 

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        String res = "{";
        try {
            for (Field field : fields) {
                res += field.getName() + " : " + field.get(this);
            }
            res += "}";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Because the `elements` tag is root element you can't use `@XmlElementWrapper`, but `items` is not root, so you can use that there, thus you don't have to implement the `Items` class.
Ignore the `toString` implementation, it's just to print the objects in a meaningful way.

**Object to XML Output**

------- Object to XML -----------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<elements>
    <element>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Test1</name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Test2</name>
            </item>
        </items>
        <property1>prop1</property1>
        <property2>prop2</property2>
        <type>2</type>
    </element>
    <element>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Test1</name>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Test2</name>
            </item>
        </items>
        <property1>prop11</property1>
        <property2>prop22</property2>
        <type>22</type>
    </element>
</elements>
```

**XML to Object Output**

```
------- XML to Object -----------

elements :
[
type : 2
property1 : prop1
property2 : prop2
items : [{id : 1name : Test1}, {id : 2name : Test2}]
, 
type : 22
property1 : prop11
property2 : prop22
items : [{id : 1name : Test1}, {id : 2name : Test2}]
]
```

Comment: Great example for a complete jaxb application!  Helped me to solve a different problem and to improve my UnitTests. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Have fun

Comment: Good example..i am able to solve the JAXB exception (converting List of XML elements into list of java objects)..+1

Comment: Thanks , your detailed answer help me solve my issue